# Сказуемое составное именное или нет?

Tags: грамматика, сказуемые

*Свойство зеркальце имело.*

Какое сказуемое?

Answer (score 1):

Простое глагольное с дополнением.

Уберем инверсию и получим:

Зеркальце имело свойство.

Если предположить, что глагол «имело» является связкой, а «свойство» именной частью, то глагол без ущерба смыслу можно заменить на «быть». В данном случае это невозможно.